# Overlap the outlines of the cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand how to overlap the two outlines of the cells such that there would be 1px which will be shared for two cells.
Below is my HTML and Js code:

```js
function genDivs(rows, cols)
{ 
 var e = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
 for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
 { 
  var row = document.createElement("div"); 
  row.className = "row";
  for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
  { 
   var cell = document.createElement("div"); 
   if(r == 10 && c == 20)
    cell.className = "gridsquare begin";
   else if(r == 10 && c == 40)
    cell.className = "gridsquare end";
      else
       cell.className = "gridsquare"; 
      row.appendChild(cell); 
  } 
  e.appendChild(row); 
 }
}

genDivs(10, 20);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  #gridContainer
  {
   
  }
  .row
  {
   display: block;
  }
  .gridsquare
  {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   outline: 1px solid rgb(175, 216, 248);
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: -4px;
   margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .begin
  {
   background-color: purple;
  }
  .end
  {
   background-color: magenta;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="gridContainer"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="HomeScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using border as an alternative of outline but the result was uneven 1 px border, for example, border was 1px 1px 1px 1px 2px 1px 1px 1px 1px 2px and so on...
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `box-shawdow` for this:

```js
function genDivs(rows, cols) {
  var e = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("div");
      if (r == 10 && c == 20)
        cell.className = "gridsquare begin";
      else if (r == 10 && c == 40)
        cell.className = "gridsquare end";
      else
        cell.className = "gridsquare";
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    e.appendChild(row);
  }
}

genDivs(10, 20);
```

```css
#gridContainer {}

.row {
  display: block;
}

.gridsquare {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(175, 216, 248) inset, 0 0 0 1px rgb(175, 216, 248);
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.begin {
  background-color: purple;
}

.end {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="gridContainer"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="HomeScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: box-shadow did work like a charm but I am missing the border from right-most and bottom-most row and column.

Comment: You just have to tweak the `box-shawdow` for the same, it same.

Comment: Thanks, I instead put the gridContainer outline. Also, can you tell me how can I center horizontally gridContainer. I tried various methods but they messed up my inner grids.

Comment: you can use this `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(175, 216, 248) inset,
            0 0 0 1px rgb(175, 216, 248);` if you want. This will give you consistent layout. Let me know if that works for you I will update my answer.

Comment: box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(175, 216, 248) inset, 1px 0px 0px rgb(175, 216, 248) inset;
This suited best for my need however right side and bottom side shadow is still invisible. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Something is better than nothing :P cheers, Hope I gave my 2 cents to you.